# Can't use chrome extensions when puppeteer open the chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

[extensions pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvqSQ.png)
The extensions menu can't use when I used the puppeteer open the chrome or chromium.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
'executablePath': executablePath,
// 'ignoreDefaultArgs': ['--enable-automation'],
'args': ['--start-maximized', '--enable-automation', '--enable-remote-extensions'],
'devtools': true,
'headless': false,
'defaultViewport': null,
'userDataDir': `${userDataDir}${storeSession.store_name}${storeSession.id}`
})
```

what should I do?

chromium Version 79.0.3937.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)

chrome 77.0.3865.120

puppeteer 1.19.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the Github thread on this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#working-with-chrome-extensions). You'll need to add the following:

```
  args: [
    '--disable-extensions-except=/path/to/extension/',
    '--load-extension=/path/to/extension/',
  ]
```

Use [the official Puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#working-with-chrome-extensions) for more help.