# Is there way to access chrome extension/plugin through python library pyppeteer?

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, headless-browser, pyppeteer

I have a use case where I need to click the browser extension/plugin while navigating the URL on headless browser in python library puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

`await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreDefaultArgs='--disable extensions')`

See [Can't use chrome extensions when puppeteer open the chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368999/cant-use-chrome-extensions-when-puppeteer-open-the-chrome)